# Messy log from Keytool when getting Hash with -exportcert (Android)

Tags: android, hash, keystore, buffer-overflow, keytool

I'm trying to get a Hash from my keystore file but instead I'm getting this messy log. Didn't find any info on this behaviour, looks like a Buffer Overflow Vulnerability. Tried regenerating keystores using both Unity and keytool utility but the problem didn't go away. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Environment: OS X

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6AJg.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is best solution for your problem, please try these solution for recovering your keystore password it can solve problem , https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki

Comment: I'm getting these logs for every keystore I create using my system, there's no need in restoring them, I just need to sign my APK